# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower' fitting logistic model data

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am running this code:

```
from sklearn import cross_validation
import numpy as np
import sys
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets, svm, metrics

digits = datasets.load_digits()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(
digits.data, digits.target, test_size=0.4, random_state=0)

clf = linear_model.LogisticRegression(X_train, y_train) 
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I am getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'

How can make the logistic model fit?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you give some more details about the error? Where does the error occur? Which line? What does the stacktrace look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't pass `X_train` and `y_train` to `LogisticRegression` constructor. You need just

```
...

clf = linear_model.LogisticRegression() 
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: the error with "lower", which lower cases upper case characters, presumably occurs because you apply it to a standard numpy array, but it only works with strings, cf the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html), or [arrays of characters](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.chararray.lower.html).

Comment: @patrick I know this. In OP code this error caused by wrong initialization of `LogisticRegression` object.

Comment: I agree, I mis-posted this comment -- it was intended as reaction to  the original post, adding to your explanation, not correcting it.

Answer (score 0):

`clf = LogisticRegression()
clf.fit(x_train,x_test)`

don't pass parameters inside LogisticRegression Model