# CountVectorizer in sklearn throws "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'"

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

Good day!

I am reading spark dataframe of small size using pyspark, then I am collecting it on the driver via toPandas and then I want to apply CountVectorizer sklearn transformator. However it throws exception. Please see example to reproduce below:

```
pyspark --master local --conf "spark.pyspark.python=/opt/anaconda/envs/bd9/bin/python3" --conf "spark.pyspark.driver.python=/opt/anaconda/envs/bd9/bin/python3"

>>> spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 1)
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(
...     [
...         (1, ["google.com", "mail.ru"]),
...         (2, ["ya.ru", "gmail.com"]),
...     ],
...     ["uid", "domains"]
... )
>>> df.show()
+---+--------------------+
|uid|             domains|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|[google.com, mail...|
|  2|  [ya.ru, gmail.com]|
+---+--------------------+

>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- uid: long (nullable = true)
 |-- domains: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

>>> pandasDf = df.toPandas()
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
>>> countVectorizer = CountVectorizer()
>>> countVectorizer.fit(pandasDf["domains"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/anaconda/envs/bd9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 836, in fit
    self.fit_transform(raw_documents)
  File "/opt/anaconda/envs/bd9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 869, in fit_transform
    self.fixed_vocabulary_)
  File "/opt/anaconda/envs/bd9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 792, in _count_vocab
    for feature in analyze(doc):
  File "/opt/anaconda/envs/bd9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 266, in <lambda>
    tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
  File "/opt/anaconda/envs/bd9/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 232, in <lambda>
    return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

How should I properly use CountVectorizer in this situation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37547914/attributeerror-numpy-ndarray-object-has-no-attribute-lower-fitting-logistic)

The issue looks like due to this : `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'`

Comment: Yes, this is what the question is about.
How should I use CountVectorizer to get rid of this error?